# Net income in Germany

Tags: taxes, germany

How can I calculate my net income in Germany? Given a salary of 40kEUR, how can I know how much I'll take home?

Comment: Welcome to Expats! Your status as an expat really doesn't influence your question. If it does and you just left out how, feel free to edit and flag to have this reopened.

Comment: How much you take home depends on how much your expenses are. The only that can be told objectively is the netto income after taxation, but still the taxes depends on your civil status and religion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many sites to run a simulation. You need to know that the gross (pre-tax) salary is called “Bruttolohn” and the take-home pay is your “Nettolohn”. Looking for “Gehaltsrechner” returns many results, among other:

- [sueddeutsche.de](http://www.sueddeutsche.de/app/jobkarriere/gehaltsrechner/)
- [spiegel.de](http://www.spiegel.de/wirtschaft/service/brutto-netto-rechner-was-von-ihrem-lohn-noch-uebrig-bleibt-a-223811.html)

As you will notice, there are a few complications as your take-home pay will depend on your province (*Land*), whether you choose for private or public insurance (you can only choose if your salary is above a particular threshold) and whether you have a partner or kids (which also determines your *Lohnsteuerklasse*).

Comment: And given no other information, just putting in 40kEUR into the calculator you will take home about 25kEUR. The amount seems about right.

Comment: @moontear Everybody could at least enter 8354 in the Freibetrag box or am I missing something?

Comment: @GaëlLaurans see http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freibetrag what is a Freibetrag, you don't need to enter there 8354

Comment: @Dirty-flow Well, I thought I knew what it was and I read this article long ago but then I am completely confused: Why wouldn't you enter it in the simulation then?

Comment: make a test with 8200 EUR salary and you will see that you have to pay 0 EUR lohnsteuer - these 8354 EUR are already calculated. the field Freibetrag is for other benefits

Comment: OK, makes sense.

Comment: Are foreigns eligible for public insurance in such case?

Comment: @RafaelKassner Certainly, in fact it's mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Take home pay will depend on your tax class and a few other things. Take a look at this [calculator](http://www.parmentier.de/steuer/steuer.htm?wagetax.htm). It has short explanations about tax categories or any other configurable thing.